# Static Routes per IP Address

Tags: routing, router

I am currently studying my Certificate IV in Networking (The first course I have ever done on networking). The current task at hand is to create a small network for a business at three sites, including 7 printers, 35 computers and 2 file servers.

This part is simple. I am current creating a report and have come to the section regarding routers and switch configuration. I'd like to cover DNS zones/forwarders and routing. I have no manuals or assistance for this; it is all study yourself.

Now I believe routing and route tables are Layer 3 (Network) devices on the OSI Model. At this level we deal with IPv4 and IPv6. My current belief is the following statement:

> In a home network the routing is controlled via the ISP using their HPE (Host Provided Equipment).

Without Layer 3 devices (such as switches and routers) on site, there is no facility to create your own routing tables for data and traffic.The reliance is on the routing on the ISP.

My belief is the following:

> In an enterprise solution, it would be beneficial to create a DNS zone
>   for www.domain.org to point to the required destination. It would then be
>   beneficial to NAT all traffic from one "site" so that effective
>   persistent routes can be created.

So in order to have this configured correctly, is the following statement effective:

The default gateway for the site is: 10.128.1.254

Firstly we setup a zone forwarder for www.domain1.org to point to the required host to the required router. On this device we have a NAT for all 10.128.1.0/24 to come off as 10.X.X.X

Based upon this address, we can configure a static route for all traffic.

Most newer routers have a GUI where you can add a persistent route (but I will delve into CLI at one point). So from here if I add the persistent route, all clients requesting www.domain1.org will abide by this route.

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  A diagram would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. It is not clear what you are asking. Please [edit] your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question. Specifically, your update has removed any question from your post. While you provide detail, there are no questions to answer. This also borders as being off topic as an education/certification question; please ask specific questions about concepts to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

Michael, there are many problems with your post. Your topology is not here so we don't know if there any routes at all to route. To be able to route the traffic to another node, you have to have it first. With one ISP, can you really create a routing difference unles you are talking about a more complicated internal network where you have multiple routers etc? Your ISP meets you at your doorstep and takes your traffic away. You don't have a say then how this traffic will be routed. You can check it by issuing a tracert command. Plus if you are writing a route for one specific public IP address, you should give 255.255.255.255 subnet mask.

If you want to change the route for all nodes in your network, it would be enough to write the route to the Layer3 device only i.e. router. You don't have to add static routes to all PCs. If everybody has the same default gateway and the gateway is located just before meeting routing alternatives then you can add the route to this device.

But Michael,It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve and what sort of setup do you have.. So I might have just talked rubbish :)

Regards..

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please review and advise?